# Proving Levy's theorem using 0-1 law

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Levy's theorem states that $S_n$ converges in probabilty implies $S_n$ converges a.s. I am aware of Ottaviani's proof using maximal inequality. But I want to prove this using Kolmogrov's 0-1 law. I am wondering if my proof idea is correct.

My idea:
Suppose $S_n \to S_\infty$ in probability. Now since the event $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = S_\infty$ is a tail event, therefore, it only takes probability $0$ or $1$. Suppose that
$$
P(\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = S_\infty) = 0,
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n \neq S_\infty \ a.s.
$$
Then there exists a subsequence $S_{nk}$ that has no further subsequence that converges to $S_\infty$ a.s. Hence, it contradicts the claim that $S_n \to S_\infty$ in probability. Therefore,
$$
P(\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = S_\infty) = 1.
$$

**Edit**:
After some thought, I don't think my proof is correct since the same argument can be used upon convergence of $X_n$ since $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ is also a tail event. But we don't have $X_n$ converges in probability implies a.s. convergence.

I think the issue is that the subsequence $S_{nk}$ we picked is not fixed as it can change when we pick a different $\omega$ from the set
$$
A = \{\omega: \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(\omega) \neq S_\infty(\omega)\}.
$$
So we can't really conclude there is a subsequence with no further subsequence that converges a.s.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Or using zero-one law just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that $\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = S_\infty \}$ is a tail event.  I agree that $\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n \text{ exists}\}$ is a tail event, but since it's a sum the specific value that it converges to depends on the early terms like $X_0$ as well.  For example, if $X_n = 0$ for $n \ge 2$ then $S_\infty = X_1$ and $X_1$ is not measurable with respect to the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

I think the mistake in your proof is around the line "there exists a subsequence $S_{n_k}$ that has no further subsequence that converges to $S_\infty$ a.s."  That subsequence depends on $\omega$, so we won't be able to use it to reach the contradiction you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that the subsequence was wrong and I added that in my edit. So do you think zero-one law won't work at all in this case? Also, in regards to your comment in your first paragraph, I have some disagreement. Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ is tail-field measurable. So if it exists, it should equal to a constant since random variable in the tail field is constant a.s. But then again, I can't disagree with your counterexample though.

Comment: Actually, regarding the counterexample in your first paragraph, it means that $X_1$ is a constant. So the $\sigma$-field it generates is the trivial $\sigma$-field $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ which is a subset of the tail-field. So $X_1$ should be tail-field measurable.

Comment: I don't think that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ is tail-field measurable, I think my counterexample shows it isn't.  I'm not sure why $X_1$ has to be constant.  $X_1$ can be any random variable you like; for specificity we could let $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$.  I'm still thinking about whether the zero-one law can be used, I'll get back to you if I think of anything.